# Trying to send email, getting "use of undeclared unidentified MFMailComposeViewController"

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to send a email message in my app. I'm trying to use the MFMailComposeViewController object, but getting a error message saying its  a "undeclared identifier"

code:

```
-(IBAction) aContact: (id) sender;
{


    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailCtrl = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        [mailCtrl setSubject:@"Your TellaFortune Card Reading"];
        //  [mailCtrl setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"drblyer@cameosurgery.com"]];
        mailCtrl.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        NSString *send;
        send=[ NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@",content,@"\n \n By www.TellaFortune.com"];
        [mailCtrl setMessageBody: send  isHTML: false];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailCtrl animated:NO];
        //      [mailCtrl release];

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[ UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Cannot send email"
                            message: @"Please check internet connection and email set up"
                            delegate: self
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                            otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Import framework "MessageUI.framework" to your project and in your .h file add

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

Answer (score 16):

For anyone who is using Swift and seeing this message:

First go to your project settings in Xcode, select **Build Phases**, then **Link Binary with Libraries**, and add "MessageUI.framework" to your project.

Then, in the Swift file in which you want to use a `MFMailComposeViewController` or implement the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`, add:

```
import MessageUI
```